# Email file only if a string is added to logfile

Tags: powershell

The code below changes UPN suffixes and logs them.  How do get I get PowerShell to email me the logfile **only** if a suffix has changed?

```psh
$domain = ([adsi]'').distinguishedName
$OU = "OU=TestUPNusers,OU=_TEST_OU_,$domain"
$suffix = '@test.UofGuelph.com'
$newsuffix = "@UofGuelph.com"
$CurrentUser= [Environment]::UserName

Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -like '*$suffix'" -SearchBase $OU | 
    foreach-object {
        $upn = $_.userprincipalname.replace("$suffix","$newsuffix") 
        logwrite "changed the UPN suffix for : $UPN on $date"
        set-aduser $_ -userprincipalname $upn
}

Function LogWrite{
    Param ([string]$logstring)
    Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}

$logfile = "c:\logs\" + $currentuser + ".log”
$date = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm}" -f (get-date)
logwrite "========================================="
logwrite "Script ran by $CurrentUser on $date"
logwrite "==============================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx) (or a similar function) if `Get-ADUser` returns any results. Ex.:

```
$users = @(Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -like '*$suffix'" -SearchBase $OU)
$users | foreach-object {
    $upn = $_.userprincipalname.replace("$suffix","$newsuffix") 
    logwrite “changed the UPN suffix for : $UPN on $date"
    set-aduser $_ -userprincipalname $upn
}

if($users.Count -gt 0) { 
    send-mailmessage -to "User01 <user01@example.com>" -from "User02 <user02@example.com>" -subject "Users has been changed" -Attachments "c:\logs\$($currentuser).log”
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is dump the log data to a variable during the script run. Then at the end check if there is stuff in the log variable.  If so write the log file then email it:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName -like '*$suffix'" -SearchBase $OU | 
   foreach-object {
     $upn = $_.userprincipalname.replace("$suffix","$newsuffix") 
        $logfile += “changed the UPN suffix for : $UPN on $date`n"
          set-aduser $_ -userprincipalname $upn
     }

if($logfile)
{
$logfile | out-file <filename>
send-mailmessage -to user@dmain.com -from person@domain.com -subject $subject -body $logfile 
}
```